# Can not redirect to proper path using angular.js ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

i have one issue regarding redirecting path in angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

> profileController.js:

```
if($('#addProfileData')[0].defaultValue=='Update'){
            var updatedata={'colg_name':$scope.colgname,'address':$scope.address,'cont_no':$scope.contno,'profile_id':id};
            console.log('userupdate',userdata);
            $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "php/profile/updateProfileData.php",
            data: updatedata,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
            alert(response.data);
            $location.path('.profile');
        },function errorCallback(response) {
            alert(response.data);
        });
        }
    }
```

here i am setting path to profile page inside success callback function.But it is redirecting to the root page after update the data.

> loginRoute.js:

```
var Admin=angular.module('Channabasavashwara',['ui.router']);
Admin.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
     .state('/', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'dashboardview/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        })
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'dashboardview/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'dashboardController'
        })
        .state('dashboard.profile', {
        url: '/profile?p_i',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/profile.html',
        controller: 'profileController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.dept', {
        url: '/dept?d_i',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/dept.html',
        controller: 'deptController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.princpal', {
        url: '/princpal?pr_i',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/princpal.html',
        controller: 'princpalController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.dept_head', {
        url: '/dept_head?dh_i',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/depthead.html',
        controller: 'deptheadController'
    })

})
```

Here after update data successfully it is redirecting to login.html page.I need after updating the data the page should redirect to profile.html page.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the line of code with `$location.path('dashboard.profile');`
That would do the need for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use **$state** instead of $location as follows:

```
$state.go('dashboard.profile')
```

Also, don't forget to inject the $state service in your controller.

If you want to use $location.path you need to use the url instead of state.

Comment: @ Tarun :  I did as per you but its not redirecting at all.

Comment: @ Tarun : No error.But after updating the page is remaining constant.

Comment: @ Tarun : I need to remove query string when `$state.go('dashboard.profile')` will be called.Any idea ?

Comment: sorry i dont get your question?

Comment: @ Tarun : Before updating data i have one id with url and i need when user will finish update it will again move back to its original state without id.I am giving you the demo url  ` http://oditek.in/Gofasto/#/dashboard/profile?p_i=1 ` open this and edit the field again.You can clear.